# Probability of there being 5 Questions with A as an answer.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

Is the probability that 5 questions on a multiple choice test out of 10 have A as answer a combination or permutation. Where AAAAABBBBB is different from BBBBBAAAAA.

This is the full question, what is the probability that a student who chooses response A for each question gets exactly 5 out of 10 questions correct?  Each question has four possible responses labeled A, B, C, or D, and the professor chose the correct keys randomly.

Am I correct in saying that the number of combinations with 5 questions being answered with A divided by $4^{10}$ is equal to the probability?

Comment: This is not clear.  How many possible answers are there for a given question?  Are we to assume that the correct answers are chosen uniformly and independently?

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned that. There are 4 possible answers to each question, A B C and D.

Comment: This is what else is given, A professor is creating a multiple choice test with 10 questions in total. Each question has four possible responses labeled A, B, C, or D. The answer key is a string of 10 values consisting of the labels of the correct answers. Suppose that the professor chooses the answer key at random from all possible answer keys (equivalently, he chooses the label of the correct answer at random for each question).

Comment: Ok.  So each guess of $A$ is correct with probability $\frac 14$, independently of all other guesses.  Which makes this a routine problem about a binomial distribution.

Comment: You say something about $4^7$.  Why $7$ and not $10$?  Where did $7$ come from?

Comment: As for "*the number of -test keys- with 5 questions being answered with A divided by -the total number of test keys- is equal to the probability*" yes, that is correct and is one way of viewing the problem.  I wouldn't call this either a combination or a permutation.  I'd call it an *arrangement*.

Comment: But is the number of questions with A as an answer a combination or permutation?

Comment: Neither.  It is more fundamental.  A result of rule of product.

Comment: Also, I haven't learned binomial distribution in my course yet.

Answer (score 4):

This can be calculated as follow.

We have $10C5=252$ different ways of picking 5 questions from 10 questions.

The probability that we pick not A is .75, so the probability that we select not A five times is $.75^{5}$.

The probability that we pick A is .25, so the probability that we select A five times is $.25^{5}$.

putting it all together we get...

$10C5*(.75^{5})*(.25^{5})≈.0584$

Answer (score 0):

Without Binomial Distribution:
Yes you are right the total number of ways the answers can be distributed is $4^{10}$. The ways in which $5$ $A's$ can be distributed must be calculated .
To do this, notice there are ${10 \choose 5}$ ways to select the places where the $A's$ must be. In the remaining five places we can have 3 options in each place namely $3^5$ combinations.
Finally the required probability is $3^5*{10 \choose 5}/4^{10}$ which equals $0.05839920043$ or approximately $0.0584$.

Comment: Nice try, but I am unable to follow this logic. This is a binomial distribution question. Please see my answer.

Comment: Also @Shaunak Apte, I just took a look at your profile: I am very impressed with you. You are only in seventh grade! I am in my 20s, but if I had as much math ability as you when I was in seventh grade, well... I would be much better than I am now! keep learning and good luck!

Comment: @bfff I am Honored! Anyways, Now I have edited my post and our answers match. Basically in my answer I have counted all the possible ways to choose answers.($4^{10}$) and then I counted the ways in which $5A's$ could appear. The mistake I was making is that the remaining five answers have $3^5$ and not $4^5$ total combinations because $a$ cannot appear.